# Data Structures in JAVA to implement joins

Tags: java, join, data-structures

Hi i am trying to implement a simple join algorithim in Java...

I have three relations i.e M(ABX) N(ACY) and O(BCZ). These relations are currently in a comma separated file and all integers(example file M will have values like 1,5,6; 2,7.9;..) was wondering what was the best data structure to use in Java to implement the join MxNxO i.e M and N will join on attribute A producing a schema(ABCXY) which will then join with O on attributes B and C producing a final result of ABXCYZ which will have all join results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specialized data structures that you can readily use for this.
You would have to represent the tables extracted from your CSV files via `List<List>>` and then you would have to iterate over the lists and compare the proper attribute representing the column name to create intermediate lists and so on until you have joined all the relations.
I.e. you would need to implement this logic yourself.
The best way for this IMHO is to follow the answer of @Ernest Friedman-Hill.
Not only will you get this functionality faster you will get it error free as you would not need to test that the join algorithm works correctly over any dataset. The embedded database will do this for you.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps an embedded database like [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) would be the right choice. It's flexible, performant, and easy to use.